# TableMenuButton dose not show name of columns which are saved as Label, JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, treetableview

I turned my column names as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28879841/4262423) to labels so that I can get tooltip on their names:

```
        for (Entry<String, String> ent : dc.getSortedAssignedOrg().entrySet()) {

        TreeTableColumn<String, ArrayList<String>> col = new TreeTableColumn<>();
        Label label = new Label(ent.getValue());
        col.setGraphic(label);
        col.setEditable(false);
        col.setSortable(false);
        label.setTooltip(new Tooltip(label.getText()));// tooltip for column
            .
            .
            .
```

Now the problem is my TableMenuButton does not show the column names, and clicking on the plus sign on the right corner of treetableview opens a list in which there are only the checked signs, which I can remove or add. But the name itself is not shown. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own table menu. You're better off with a custom menu anyway, since the in-built menu e. g. closes each time you click on a button. Unfortunately there is no getter for the context menu, so you'll have to find access to it either via reflection or a lookup.

I created a gist for a custom menu via the [reflection](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/7a2701f267588a2ecf31) and the [lookup](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/d92829cdf5e5fee6fee9) mechanism. Maybe it's of help for you.

The relevant part for you would be

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(tableColumn.getText());
```

where you set the menu item to the text of your preferrence, i. e. the text of your labels.

---

Here's a lookup version for TreeTableView:

CustomTreeTableMenuDemo.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomTreeTableMenuDemo extends Application {

    List<Employee> employees = Arrays.<Employee> asList(new Employee(
            "Ethan Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"), new Employee(
            "Emma Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"), new Employee(
            "Michael Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"), new Employee(
            "Anna Black", "anna.black@example.com"), new Employee(
            "Rodger York", "roger.york@example.com"), new Employee(
            "Susan Collins", "susan.collins@example.com"));

    final TreeItem<Employee> root = new TreeItem<>(new Employee(
            "Sales Department", ""));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle("Table Menu Demo");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        root.setExpanded(true);
        employees.stream().forEach((employee) -> {
            root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(employee));
        });
        stage.setTitle("Tree Table View Sample");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 400, 400);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        Group sceneRoot = (Group) scene.getRoot();

        TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> empColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>(
                "Employee");
        empColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
        empColumn
                .setCellValueFactory((
                        TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(
                        param.getValue().getValue().getName()));

        TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> emailColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>(
                "Email");
        emailColumn.setPrefWidth(190);
        emailColumn
                .setCellValueFactory((
                        TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(
                        param.getValue().getValue().getEmail()));

        TreeTableView<Employee> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(root);
        treeTableView.getColumns().setAll(empColumn, emailColumn);

        sceneRoot.getChildren().add(treeTableView);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // enable table menu button and add a custom menu to it
        TreeTableUtils.addCustomTreeTableMenu(treeTableView);
    }

    public class Employee {

        private SimpleStringProperty name;
        private SimpleStringProperty email;

        public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
            if (name == null) {
                name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
            }
            return name;
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty emailProperty() {
            if (email == null) {
                email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email");
            }
            return email;
        }

        private Employee(String name, String email) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String fName) {
            name.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

TreeTableUtils.java

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeTableViewSkin;

public class TreeTableUtils {

    /**
     * Make table menu button visible and replace the context menu with a custom context menu via reflection.
     * The preferred height is modified so that an empty header row remains visible. This is needed in case you remove all columns, so that the menu button won't disappear with the row header.
     * IMPORTANT: Modification is only possible AFTER the table has been made visible, otherwise you'd get a NullPointerException
     * @param treeTableView
     */
    public static void addCustomTreeTableMenu( TreeTableView treeTableView) {

        // enable table menu
        treeTableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);

        // replace internal mouse listener with custom listener 
        setCustomContextMenu( treeTableView);

    }

    private static void setCustomContextMenu( TreeTableView treeTableView) {

        TreeTableViewSkin<?> treeTableViewSkin = (TreeTableViewSkin<?>) treeTableView.getSkin();

        // get all children of the skin
        ObservableList<Node> children = treeTableViewSkin.getChildren();

        // find the TableHeaderRow child
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {

            Node node = children.get(i);

            if (node instanceof TableHeaderRow) {

                TableHeaderRow tableHeaderRow = (TableHeaderRow) node;

                // setting the preferred height for the table header row
                // if the preferred height isn't set, then the table header would disappear if there are no visible columns
                // and with it the table menu button
                // by setting the preferred height the header will always be visible
                // note: this may need adjustments in case you have different heights in columns (eg when you use grouping)
                double defaultHeight = tableHeaderRow.getHeight();
                tableHeaderRow.setPrefHeight(defaultHeight);

                for( Node child: tableHeaderRow.getChildren()) {

                    // child identified as cornerRegion in TableHeaderRow.java
                    if( child.getStyleClass().contains( "show-hide-columns-button")) {

                        // get the context menu
                        ContextMenu columnPopupMenu = createContextMenu( treeTableView);

                        // replace mouse listener
                        child.setOnMousePressed(me -> {
                            // show a popupMenu which lists all columns
                            columnPopupMenu.show(child, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                            me.consume();
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a menu with custom items. The important thing is that the menu remains open while you click on the menu items.
     * @param cm
     * @param treeTableView
     */
    private static ContextMenu createContextMenu( TreeTableView treeTableView) {

        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

        // create new context menu
        CustomMenuItem cmi;

        // select all item
        Label showAll = new Label("Show all");
        showAll.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                for (Object obj : treeTableView.getColumns()) {
                    ((TableColumn<?, ?>) obj).setVisible(true);
                }
            }

        });

        cmi = new CustomMenuItem(showAll);
        cmi.setHideOnClick(false);
        cm.getItems().add(cmi);

        // deselect all item
        Label hideAll = new Label("Hide all");
        hideAll.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                for (Object obj : treeTableView.getColumns()) {
                    ((TableColumn<?, ?>) obj).setVisible(false);
                }
            }

        });

        cmi = new CustomMenuItem(hideAll);
        cmi.setHideOnClick(false);
        cm.getItems().add(cmi);

        // separator
        cm.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());

        // menu item for each of the available columns
        for (Object obj : treeTableView.getColumns()) {

            TreeTableColumn<?, ?> tableColumn = (TreeTableColumn<?, ?>) obj;

            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(tableColumn.getText());
            cb.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(tableColumn.visibleProperty());

            cmi = new CustomMenuItem(cb);
            cmi.setHideOnClick(false);

            cm.getItems().add(cmi);
        }

        return cm;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I change TableHeaderRow to TreeTableHeaderRow?

Comment: Just replace everything TableHeaderRow with TreeTableHeaderRow. Of course you'll have to adapt to tree, eg cast to TreeTableViewSkin instead of TableViewSkin.

Comment: I changed everything but TreeTableHeaderRow is not known and throws TreeTableHeaderRow cannot be resolved to a type error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check. You don't have to change it, leave it at TableHeaderRow. But you do need to change TableColumn to TreeTableColumn. I changed the answer and added an example.